# Extend vertical line in polynom division

Tags: rules, polynom

I have this MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{polynom}

\begin{document}

\polylongdiv[style=D]{x^3+x^2-4}{x+2}   

\end{document}
```

With this output

[image]

What I want is to extend the vertical line to the end of division like image below

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Expanding upon Ulrike's patch to automate the process.  Here, with `\mypolylongdiv`,  the `\polylongdiv` is done twice for each problem, the first time to measure the drop height of the line and the 2nd time to apply it.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{polynom,xpatch}

\newlength\mypolydepth

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\pld@ArrangeResult{\vrule height 2.25ex}{\rule{0pt}{2.2ex}\smash{\vrule height 2.25ex depth \mypolydepth}}{}{\fail}
\makeatother 

\newcommand\mypolylongdiv[3][style=D]{%
  \setlength\mypolydepth{0pt}%
  \setbox0=\hbox{\polylongdiv[#1]{#2}{#3}}%
  \setlength\mypolydepth{\dimexpr\dp0-1.3\baselineskip}%
  \polylongdiv[#1]{#2}{#3}%
}
\begin{document}
\mypolylongdiv{x^2-4}{x+2}\medskip

\mypolylongdiv{x^3+x^2-4}{x+2}\medskip

\mypolylongdiv{x^4+x^2-4}{x+2}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: External measuring is cheating ;-). The question is if one can get the value from the code. There is `\pld@maxcol` but depending on the polynom it is a bit to short or to long.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  "All's fair in love and TeX"

Answer (score 4):

I can make the line longer but I see no easy way to get the needed length automatically:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{polynom,xpatch}

\newlength\mypolydepth

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\pld@ArrangeResult{\vrule height 2.25ex}{\rule{0pt}{2.2ex}\smash{\vrule height 2.25ex depth \mypolydepth}}{}{\fail}
\makeatother 

\setlength\mypolydepth{6\baselineskip} %manual value


\begin{document}

\polylongdiv[style=D]{x^3+x^2-4}{x+2}

\end{document}
```

[image]